# Create Picture in Picture (PIP) Effect iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to create PIP Effect like displayed in below Image.
The background Image is blur. I have this bottle with transparent Image. But how can implement this.

1) I add image view that contains background blur image.

2) Then I add the bottle image view that contains transparent bottle.

3) And then add the original image view that contains original image. But how to fit this original image into this bottle.

Thanks..

[image]

Comment: You should try GPUImage https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: In which library i want to use..from GPUImage

Comment: I assume you asking which filters you need to use. you should find the right blur filter and blend filter you need. Why don't you put the sample images so maybe people could try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your question .and as your question i upload my code on my GITHUB repository.See the below link and get your solution . 
[PIP-Effects](https://github.com/divyeshdobariya/PIP-Effects) I hope this is helpful for you..Enjoy

Comment: Hi, can you suggest me how you get those frames directly

Comment: Can you please tell how did you get the exact frame  for behindView.